# Aggregated data at intermediate network nodes when sending data possible?

Tags: networking, network-programming, aggregate, aggregate-functions, network-efficiency

I have a problem understanding what's possible when developing applications that are very much based on data transfer through public networks.

**Scenario & Question**
Two or more devices have gathered data and are to send it to a receiver (always the same receiver). Is it possible to make routers throughout the route to combine the data in order to decrease the bandwidth, increase privacy, decrease bottlenecks, etc? If so, where can you start to learn about how to do this?

**Example**
Devices A, B, and C are all to send data to the same receiver, for example, Google. At the first hop A and B reaches the same router (1). Router 1 combines the data from A & B. C's data was sent to another router (2). At hop 5 for AB-combined data and hop 8 for C, the data reaches the same router (3) which then aggregates the data and sends it to the receiver.

Super thankful for any advice or pointers you could give me.

Comment: IP is connectionless, each packet is routed independently, regardless of what has come before. The job of a router is to route packets and forward them as fast as possible. A router cannot relate any packet to any other packet.

Answer (score 0):

No, routers do not combine data, and there are no plans to implement this AFAIK.